# can not convert from to Xamarin form page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am trying to load a class with the click event on my main page but it gives me following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'LocalDataAccess.recipe1' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

This is my code:

```
private async void recipe_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new recipe1());
}
```

[image]

Comment: recipe1 should using Xamarin.forms and Inherint from ContentPage, so you should do the following on recipe1: Using Xamiarn.forms; Class Recipe1:ContentPage

Comment: Fixed english, image and added error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`recipe1` should using `Xamarin.Forms` and `Inherit` from `ContentPage`, so you should do the following on `recipe1`:

`using Xamarin.Forms;`

`class Recipe1:ContentPage` – Mike Darwish "

This is work fine!

Comment: Also you should change the `<ContentView/>` from `.xaml` to  `<ContentPage/>`